# Divergence of sequence $y_n=(1-x_1)(1-\ x_2)\cdots(1-x_n)$ if $x_{n+1}=(x_{n+1}+1)x_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\ x_n$ be a sequence of real numbers so that $\ x_1$ is between $-1$ and $0$ and $\ x_{n+1}={(\ x_{n+1}+1)}{\ x_n}$ , $n$ is a natural number. Show that $\ y_n= \ (1-\ x_1)(1-\ x_2)\cdots(1-\ x_n)$ is divergent. And I observed that $\ x_{n+1}=\dfrac{\ x_n}{1-\ x_n}$ but I found no reccurencial form for $\ y_n$ or any clue on how to prove it doesn't converge.

Comment: First note that $$1-x_n=\frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}$$ implies $$y_n=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{x_k}{x_{k+1}}=\frac{x_1}{x_{n+1}}$$ Re $(x_n)$, note that $$\frac1{x_{n+1}}=\frac1{x_n}-1$$ hence $$\frac1{x_{n+1}}=\frac1{x_1}-n$$ Can you finish this?

Comment: So $\ y_n= \ x_1 - \ {x_1}{n}$ and because of this, by assuming it has a limit, it gives you that limit is -infinity and therefore the assumption is false? Is this approach correct?

Comment: Actually, $y_n=1-nx_1$, from which the divergence to $+\infty$ should be clear without any proof by contradiction.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to simplify that x1. Well, thank you!

Comment: You might want to write an answer explaining all this in detail and to post it below, this is actually recommended by the rules of the site.

Comment: ...and then you can accept your own answer. You won't get any points for being the answerer, but it'll mean that the question is "closed out" and doesn't hang there for all eternity on the unanswered-questions list.

Comment: The answer belongs to Did. I just fullfiled a formality( I call it a formality not in a pejorative way, as I think the reasons why I have to answer the question are clear).

Comment: The computations in my comment certainly do not "belong" to anybody. You are free to accept your answer. (Only, remember that $x_1<0$ hence $1-nx_1\to+\infty$, not $-\infty$...)

Answer (score 3):

In continuation of what I did, we have that $$1-x_n=\frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}$$ which implies $$y_n=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{x_k}{x_{k+1}}=\frac{x_1}{x_{n+1}}$$ Re the sequence $(x_n)$, note that $$\frac1{x_{n+1}}=\frac1{x_n}-1$$ hence $$\frac1{x_{n+1}}=\frac1{x_1}-n$$ From this one gets $$y_n=1-nx_1$$ from which the divergence to $+\infty$ follows.